# Example of continuous function with values in a closed set

Tags: calculus

Give an example of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and an open set so that $f\left(A\right)$ is not an open set.

So basically I need to find a continuous function that is defined on an open set that takes values in a closed one, I think. Anyone have any idea on how I can find such a function?

Comment: A constant function?

Comment: Doesn't specify. It just says continuous.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=sin(x)$ in the interval (-10,10). In fact any open interval of length more than $2\pi$ will work.

Comment: So my closed interval on which the function takes values will be $[-1,1]$, right?

Answer (score 2):

Pick any point $x_0$ and define $ f(x) =  x_0 $ for all $x$.

Comment: Is it that easy? So I can just have $f\left(x\right)=4$ which would mean $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \left\{4\right\}$ ?